# Commercially available 3D printer fume and UFP extractor

Tags: diy-3d-printer, safety, enclosure

Is there a commercially available fume and nano particle extractor for a 3D printer, like the Ultimaker3 extended?  I'm looking for a safe solution, to use at home, for around $800.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following on from Harvey Lim's [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/commercially-available-3d-printer-fume-and-ufp-extractor#answer-3977), to give a concrete example of a DIY filter, which uses active carbon, see [ABS 3d Printer Nanoparticle and Chemical Exhaust Air Filter](https://web.archive.org/web/20200514160332/http://www.3dprintfilemarket.com/140629194058.html):

> ###Description
> Enclose your 3d printer and use this exhaust air filter along with a recirculating air filter to eliminate nanoparticles and chemical fumes. 95 to 99.5% of partilces up to 0.1 micron in size are filtered before air is exhausted into your 3d printing room. This is 3 times better than HEPA filtration. Chemical fumes such as phenols, hydrogen bromide, hydrogen cyanide, and styrene are also filtered out. The amount of chemicals filtered out depends on the amount of carbon filtration media you put into the unit and the strength of the fan you install on the unit. If you are using this for business purposes, you'll have to experiment a bit to have it pass inspection. If you are using it for personal purposes, know that the human nose is extremely sensitive. People who have the gene for hydrogen cyanide detection can smell it down to a concentration of 2 to 10 ppm. Suffice it to say, that if you can smell no evil, you are probably not experiencing evil. This has totally cleared my 3d printing room of nasty fumes. I invite you to try it out for yourself as the cost is very low since I've designed it to use surgical masks and aquarium activated carbon filtration media, which is very affordable. You should change the filtration media and surgical mask every month or 50 hours of printing, whichever comes first. I offer no warranty of any kind as this is an experimental device.

This filter is mentioned in [tbm0115's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/513/what-are-the-best-air-filtration-options-for-enclosures#answer-539) to [What are the best air filtration options for enclosures?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/513/what-are-the-best-air-filtration-options-for-enclosures)

Answer (score 2):

At the current moment, commercial fume extractors are quite rare in the market, but there are companies releasing some this year (like the [3DKreator's SYNE system](http://3dkreator.com/en/blog/warning-typical-desktop-3d-printer-emits-hazardous-particles-and-compounds-during-3d-printing-are-we-in-trouble)). However all commercial forms of it are quite expensive.

What I would do would be using an active carbon filter with a fan.

Comment: *active carbon filter with a fan*... An example of which is [ABS 3d Printer Nanoparticle and Chemical Exhaust Air Filter](http://www.3dprintfilemarket.com/140629194058.html)

Comment: The Syne system is still mentioned on their website but I can’t find where it ca be purchased.

Answer (score 2):

Dust collectors, fume extractors, and mist collectors for other industrial processes like welding, machining, and woodworking start at a few thousand dollars.

The Allerair AirMedic Pro 6 (formerly 6000 series) is available from as low as $600. It is marketed in some places as an air purifier but others as a general purpose air filter. In any case it uses activated carbon and a HEPA filter.

Answer (score 1):

[Matterhackers](https://www.matterhackers.com/s/store?q=Print%20pro%20bofa) and [Printedsolid](https://www.printedsolid.com/collections/vendors?q=BOFA) both carry the BoFa Print Pro filters. The Print Pro 3 has the benefit of recirculating the filtered air so that it doesn’t drop the enclosure temperature as much. Printed solid has it for \$899 currently. The filters are about \$300 to replace the prefilter and the combined Hepa/carbon filter.

Greenonline's answer gives a DIY solution that seems like a good option. Surgical masks won’t have a very high filter capacity though.

None of the other answers give a commercial filter solution that is available without also buying an enclosure.

Comment: the filter capacity depends on the mask and filter: Surgical masks have little to no filter capacity, an respirator filter on the other hand is designed to filter out particles till breathing gets harder (which can take weeks). NRBC Masks designed to keep you alive in a warzone like the M17 mask have filter regulations when to exchange them - for example TM 3-4240-279-10 says ["replace after 24 hours or after any attack or if damaged or imersed in water"](https://www.survivalistboards.com/showpost.php?s=9e10b7f2b89f2cb6bb3eba247b8bc7fa&p=14683353&postcount=2)

Answer (score 0):

To try to answer your question, I found these enclosures on [3DPrintClean](https://www.3dprintclean.com/store-1/), by browsing the Ultimaker forum. I'm not sure it fits your needs since you did not give any details about which Ultimaker you have, nor the amount of money you are willing to spend.

Comment: Your link did not work. Here is the correct link : https://www.3dprintclean.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are two main options you could consider. The first being a diy filter and the second being a commercially available fume extractor.

---

**Option 1**

You could make a filter yourself. On Thingiverse, there are many ideas that you could implement. A few examples are these :

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1992079

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2285882

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2105113

---

**Option 2**

Buy a commercially available fume filter. An example that would be well below your budget ($178) would be the Zimpure (https://www.zimple3d.com/zimpure/). This is a device that will vacuum the fumes right by the nozzle and filter them. Additionally, you could get this filter from Matterhackers : [MatterHackers](https://www.matterhackers.com/store/l/3d-printpro-2-fume-extractor/sk/M148KJM4?rcode=GAT9HR&gclid=CjwKCAjw27jnBRBuEiwAdjQXDAJL0tK7g4mAGvHf1ThJigJ80j920qelXJXtdOLcufKXE2Dkd2ZfUxoCzdsQAvD_BwE). This could be an option if you are willing to go a little bit above your budget. If you would rather have a filter for 30 bucks, you can also look at this filter that attaches to your enclosure : https://www.3dupfitters.com/products/fan-and-charcoal-air-filter.

Lastly, if you wanted to go all out, you could also get this enclosure : https://www.3dprintclean.com/.

---

I hope any of these solutions named might be beneficial to you :). For even more options, visit this post : [What air filtration options exist for enclosures?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/513/what-air-filtration-options-exist-for-enclosures)