# Enclosures (w.r.t. emissions) useful for not only printing ABS?

Tags: abs, enclosure

I've been reading and seeing a lot of texts on the internet and videos on YouTube claiming that enclosures are both beneficial and not so beneficial. My main concern though is the possible toxic fumes emission. I suffer from respiratory problems, and the last thing I need is a new poison in the air.

Is ABS the only filament product I have to be careful with, or are there others I should worry about?

Comment: Please note that the question is not very simply answered, what filaments are you expecting to print? Note that toxic fumes aren't the only things emitted from printers, also fine particles are being emitted. If you are concerned with the possible toxic emissions you should read [Should I enclose my 3D Printer?](/q/1292/) and [What air filtration options exist for enclosures?](/q/513). E.g. POM emits toxic fumes too, but I wonder if you are going to print this, it is pretty difficult filament to print.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What air filtration options exist for enclosures?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/513/what-air-filtration-options-exist-for-enclosures)

Comment: Other filaments need much higher temperature to print, making enclosures mandatory. But all these are non-standard. On the other hand, a resin printer can **also** benefit from a proper airtight enclosure to prevent resin emissions.